# Flink CEP iterative condition for single pattern in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-flink, complex-event-processing, flink-cep

The problem i am facing is that I am unable to perform a sum on a single CEP pattern in scala. I want to detect when sum is greater than 6100 for a particular customerID. I am providing a keyed stream to the CEP.pattern(...). I have provided my code below for pattern construction.

```
val pattern1 =Pattern.begin[GenericRecord]("start").where((v,ctx) => {

      lazy val sum= ctx.getEventsForPattern("start").map(_.get("amount").toString.toInt).sum

      print((sum + v.get("amount").toString.toLong).toString)
     //print(sum+v.get("amount").toString.toLong>6100)
      //println(v.get("customer_id").toString+v.get("amount").toString+" , ")
      (sum+v.get("amount").toString.toLong)>6100 && v.get("state").toString=="FAILED"
    }).oneOrMore
```

My input is in avro format and Flink is consuming it from kafka. The input looks like this -:

````
{"trasanction_id":196,"customer_id":28,"datetime":"2017-09-01 12:35:08","amount":6094,"state":"FAILED"}
{"trasanction_id":198,"customer_id":27,"datetime":"2017-09-01 12:36:04","amount":6024,"state":"FAILED"}
{"trasanction_id":199,"customer_id":27,"datetime":"2017-09-01 12:36:05","amount":2399,"state":"FAILED"}
{"trasanction_id":197,"customer_id":28,"datetime":"2017-09-01 12:36:36","amount":547,"state":"FAILED"}```
````

However, below code runs well while using two patterns-:

```
val pattern1=Pattern.begin[GenericRecord]("start").followedBy("middle").where((v,ctx) => {

      lazy val sum= ctx.getEventsForPattern("start").map(_.get("amount").toString.toInt).sum

      print((sum + v.get("amount").toString.toLong).toString)
     //print(sum+v.get("amount").toString.toLong>6100)
      //println(v.get("customer_id").toString+v.get("amount").toString+" , ")
      (sum+v.get("amount").toString.toLong)>6100 && v.get("state").toString=="FAILED"
    }).oneOrMore
```

Comment: Hi David, I was trying to show you the code for which I was getting the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getEventsForPattern` returns values already matched by the pattern. Let's analyze customer `27`. When processing event

```
{"trasanction_id":198,"customer_id":27,"datetime":"2017-09-01 12:36:04","amount":6024,"state":"FAILED"}
```

your first snippet rejects this message as it is not satisfying condition: `sum + amount = 0 + 6094 < 6100`. When processing

```
{"trasanction_id":197,"customer_id":28,"datetime":"2017-09-01 12:36:36","amount":547,"state":"FAILED"}
```

your condition will once again be checking if `0 + 547 > 6100` and this is why you see no output.

In your second example you are using `followedBy` operator which mean that you are going to process pairs of elements. First transaction is accepted unconditionally (as you are not including `where` operator) and now it is going to be returned by `ctx.getEventsForPattern("start")` call. I hope you know understand behaviour of this code.

---

`CEP` is mostly used to spot patterns in data, not to aggregate them. Your problem can be approached by doing windowing followed by filtering - no need to use `CEP` here.

Comment: CEP sorts event time streams before doing pattern matching. This can be a reason to use it even in cases where the pattern is trivial.

Comment: @bottaio thanks for clearing the confusion. However, what if I want to match patterns according to certain aggregated value. How to use Iterative condition for that? I was thinking of using windowing and then CEP, but, in that case, there will be clash between CEP's "within" time and "window" time, perhaps. I am not sure about it. Can u pls clarify on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have partitioned values by customer_id, so sorting would not be an issue I guess, because sorting will be done per partition.